# Software to type fewest characters

Tags: productivity, keyboard

As I was learning shorthand, I read about alphabetic shorthand's such as [Speedwriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedwriting), which basically removes unimportant vowels, has some single letters stand for prefixes and suffixes, etc. Usually it's used as handwriting, written in cursive to increase speed. But I thinking something like stenotype on computer program that would automatically transcribe the shortened word into the longform.

Is there currently a software for what I'm thinking of?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.openstenoproject.org/

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for, but I'd have to learn Easyscript: http://easyscript.com/demos/demo_computerscript.asp